# Why does MySQL not automatically create a temporary index for appropriate queries?

Tags: mysql

I realize this is a sort of meta-programming question, but I'm assuming there are enough experienced people here to give a decent answer.

I was just building a query again, to retrieve some data from a table.

```
SELECT pl.field1, pl.field2
FROM table pl
LEFT JOIN table2 dp on pl.field1 = dp.field1
WHERE dp.field1 IS NULL
```

Executing this query took ages (1800+ seconds).

After I got sick of waiting, and made the effort to `EXPLAIN` the query, it turned out that a full table scan was done.

I created an index on dp.field1 and the query was almost instant thereafter, creating that index took less than a second.

Judging from the `EXPLAIN`, this wasn't too difficult to determine. Why can't, or won't, MySQL do this automatically? Spending just a second to create that index will make the query instant, so MySQL could theoretically create a temporary index, use it to do the query and then remove it again, which would still be orders of magnitude faster than the alternative.

I'm expecting the usual answers of 'to make sure you design a good schema' or 'mysql just does what you tell it to do', but I'm wondering if there might be a technical reason why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Probably can be done for a limited number of situations,yes software can always be better.

Comment: Because MySQL can't know if you are willing to trade insert/update/delete speed vs. select speed.

Comment: 1800 seconds...? It took 30 minutes to complete?

Comment: Computing if a temporary index would make the query faster might not be such an easy problem, and such a computation would take time, anyway. It would take time even when the db designer decided that such an index wasn't useful : this would slow down all queries, even when the designer properly did his job. One could imagine a feature like a session parameter telling mysql that the db isn't optimized for the queries that are sent but it looks like a not so obvious feature.

Comment: @dystroy similar to vim there could be a "beginner" mode which has the check and and advanced mode which doesnt set by the ini file ?

Comment: You are expected to "know what you are doing" when using a relational database.

Comment: @user1281385 Yes. Maybe not a "beginner" mode, because there can always be the case where you have a properly designed db and you have a one-time very specific query. But this kind of smart query runner looks like a hard and specific thing to develop. And as experienced db users probably wouldn't use it, the "market" seems to be thin.

Comment: @dystroy beyond a certain table size, it would almost always be useful, especially for simple queries like this one.

Comment: @TimothyChoi Indeed. The tables both contain about 200k rows, which I suspect has something to do with it.

Comment: @Aeolun A problem I see is this one : Users seeing the query looks OK (runs in 1 s) and not creating the index, even in production, while with the properly made index it would run in 3 ms. The end result might be a bunch of slow applications...

Comment: This interesting question appears to be off-topic because it is about why a specific feature hasn't made its way into a popular software. It's also open ended and opinion based.

Comment: @dystroy Not exactly. Because people would still investigate what is making the query slow if 1 second is too slow for their purposes.

Also, the question is about whether there is a technical reality that makes this impossible. But I see your point (made by the 12 comments already written here).

Comment: @MarcusAdams I voted to close with the specific reason I gave 2 hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply - because the idea doesn't really scale using the current design of RDBMS engines.

It's okay for a single user, but databases are designed to support many concurrent users, and having each user's query also run a speculative optimization step ("can I speed up this query by creating an index?"), and creating that index, which in some circumstances is a very expensive operation, would become slow at any degree of scale. Having the index be "single use" would be wasteful of both computation time and disk space, but having lots of permanent indices in turn would slow down the query optimizer by having to investigate many indices for a given query. It would also slow down data modification operations.

Admittedly, on modern hardware, these concerns are a lot less significant - basic design of RDBMS engines dates back to the days when disk space was expensive, CPUs were several orders of magnitude slower, and memory was an unimaginable luxury.

Answer (score 2):

For columns with low cardinality it is not a good idea to use a B-Tree Index. B-Trees become degenerated for low cardinalities and do in fact increase query time in comparison to a full table scan.

So always creating a B-Tree index is not a good idea. At least it have to consider cardinality, too. And maybe several other things, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only speaking for MySQL because there may be a database system out there that automatically modifies your database design.

The simple answer is, MySQL simply does what you tell it to do.

MySQL cannot predict the future. Only you can. You know much more about your data than MySQL does. MySQL keeps some statistics, but it's guessing the best way to execute your query on very sparse information (that is sometimes outdated) before it actually tries to do so. Once it starts executing, it doesn't change its plan, no matter how wrong the guess was.

The methods that it uses to guess are all very well documented. It's our job to provide the indexes that will provide the most benefit, and even, at times, hint that it should use those indexes.

If you tell MySQL to perform a query that requires a table scan, it assumes you know that it's going to do a table scan, because it told you in its documentation that it would. It simply obeys.

Database systems that don't allow the DBA to make decisions don't scale well. There are always tradeoffs to be made, and you're the one to make them. MySQL is a hammer, not a carpenter.